# How do I get the ?! regex operator to work properly?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a search string and use regex to find me everything that is not equal to it.

i.e. like this

```
string searchStr = SearchStr;
searchStr = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape(searchStr).
    Replace(@"\*", ".+").
    Replace(@"\?", ".");
//if (searchStr.StartsWith("!"))//(?!hede).)
//    searchStr = "?!" + searchStr.Substring(1);
```

then I do Regex.isMatch but I cannot get the `?!` to do a not the following pattern, any ideas?

Comment: For a start lookaheads and lookbehinds are required to be enclosed in brackets, for example `(?!dontcontainme)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can't just append ?! at the start, you would need to make a negative lookahead group, and depending on what/how you are searching you'd want to anchor it. Something like this might work depending on what you're doing:

```
searchStr = "^(?!" + searchStr.Substring(1) + "$).*";
```

It would probably be easier to negate the regex result though:

```
Regex r = new Regex(..);
Match m = r.Match(someText);
if (m.Success != searchStr.StartsWith("!")) {
  // matches!
}
```

You'd want the regex to succeed (return **true**) when `.StartsWith("!")` is **false** and vice versa.

Comment: thanks you saying just invert result made me twig it,
bool invertSearch = searchStr.StartsWith("!");
if (invertSearch)
   searchStr = searchStr.Substring(1);

if (Regex.IsMatch(nd.Text, searchStr, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) ^ invertSearch)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for words which are not equal to `something`, try:

```
\b(?!something\b)\w+\b
```

And to build it programmatically:

```
String.Format(@"\b(?!{0}\b)\w+\b", Regex.Escape(negativeSearchStr))
```

Explanation:

```
\b\w+\b
```

is the pattern for words

```
(?!something)
```

is the negative look-ahead that word does not start with `something`. And finally:

```
(?!something\b)
```

is the negative look-ahead that word is not equal to `something`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to avoid strings that do not start with a term, you're going to be using a lookbehind. Lookbehinds and lookaheads should be enclosed in parentheses. Right now, it seems you're just doing a literal search if you don't add the parentheses, as in you are searching for a string that actually has a question mark and an exclamation mark in them.

So let's say we have strings "abc" and "bbc" and we want to find the string that doesn't start with an a. Your lookbehind regex will look like this.

```
(?<!a)b
```